# Display EditText value in another TextView after edit

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I have an EditText where the user inputs a string.  After edit, the string is displayed in a TextView.  I created a custom class called TextValidator which implements TextWatcher, to satisfy the parameters of the addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) method.  When I run it, the moment I press a letter to input into the editText, the app crashes.

In the MainActivity:

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextValidator((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)));
```

In my TextValidator class:

```
public class TextValidator extends Activity implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText editText;

    public TextValidator(EditText editText) {
        this.editText = editText;
    }

    public void validate(TextView textView, String text)
    {
        //I want to later check the string for valid format
    }

    final public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(editText.getText().toString());
        //validate(textView, text);
    }
```

Comment: Fatal Exception: Main;
java.lang.NullPointerException;

it was in this line:
final public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(editText.getText().toString());
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextValidator do not extend Activity.

Solution:

```
public class TextValidator implements TextWatcher {
    private Context mContext;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private TextView mTextView;

    public TextValidator(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        EditText mEditText = (EditText)mContext.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        TextView mTextView = (TextView)mContext.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    public void validate(TextView textView, String text)
    {
        //I want to later check the string for valid format
    }

    final public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        mTextView.setText(mEditText.getText().toString());
        //validate(textView, text);
    }
    ....
```

Comment: Then how would I call findViewById in afterTextChanged?

Comment: I put the solution in my post

Comment: I used your code, the same thing happened (app stopped the moment I pressed a letter or number into the EditText).

Comment: don't forget to change in the MainActivity : editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextValidator(this));

Comment: And decompose this line mTextView.setText(mEditText.getText().toString()); to see what is null. For example you can test if (mTextView == null) or if (mEditText == null) or if (mEditText.getText() == null)

Comment: Still getting crash, but I think I know where.  When I put mTextView.setText("hi") in the constructor, it works.  However, when I put it inside the afterTextChanged(Editable s), it crashes.  Same if using mEditText.  Any ideas?